# Identify the destination in HTTPS connections

Tags: https

How does the browser figure out the destination in an HTTPS connection? All the headers are encrypted..

Update:No this is not a homework.. my name is student because I'll always be learning in this HUGE awesome field

Comment: Your name is student?  And this is homework?

Comment: I don't think it was directly homework, but maybe he was working on some homework and a confusion about the protocol arose. This doesn't sound like a homework question to me.

Answer (score 2):

When a browser views an url like https://www.gmail.com/ first thing your browser does is resolves `www.gmail.com` to `72.14.213.19`.

Next your browser opens up a TCP connection to `72.14.213.19` on port 443.

The browser & server before ANY headers are transmitted negotiate a public key encryption scheme (RSA) based on the SSL Certificate that is digitally signed.

In this process the browser checks the certificate authenticity before communicating.

Once this trust between client & server has been established, the client now can encrypt the headers in a way the server can decrypt. It proceeds to make the HTTP request inside the SSL Tunnel.

The server decrypts the message, serves the request and encrypts it in a way that that particular client can decrypt.

The browser then decrypts the response, reads the headers and makes decisions about how to proceed from there.

This has been an overview of an HTTPS connection event. :D

Comment: wow thanks.. but then why can't proxy filters block https? if the ip addresses are sent out in the open..

Comment: Most likely because the traffic goes across a different port. (443) The proxy is probably not catching/forwarding HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The string containing https: that you typed in the browser is what the browser uses. That is not encrypted,

Answer (score 0):

Probably more than you'd ever want or need to know about the [The First Few Milliseconds of an HTTPS Connection](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html)  I'd go into more detail explaining stuff if your username wasn't student, and this wasn't likely homework.

Comment: thanks for the link.. no this is not a homework. so if the destination ip is sent out in the clear, why can't proxy servers block https?